# How can I parse a YAML file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ansible, yaml

Im currently trying to parse an Ansible hosts.yaml file with the current content

```
all:
  masters:
    master_1: 
      ansible_host: ""
      image: ""
  workers:
    worker_1:
      ansible_host: ""
      image: ""
    worker_2:
      ansible_host: ""
      image: ""
```

In nodeJS with a library 'js-yaml', but the object it creates is

```
{
  all: {
    masters: { 
      master_1: {
        ansible_host: ""
        image: ""
      }
    },
    workers: { 
      worker_1: {
        ansible_host: ""
        image: ""
      }, 
      worker_2: {
        ansible_host: ""
        image: ""
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is being able to loop over the masters/workers hosts. I would expect it to have been an array like

```
{
  all: {
    masters: [ 
      { master_1: {
          ansible_host: ""
          image: ""
        }
      },
      {...}...
    ],
    workers: [ 
      {...},
      {...}...
    ]
  }
}
```

or something similar where I can get the count of the hosts and read the vars for the hosts. I also need to save it back to the hosts.yaml for ansible to use without errors. Is there something missing? Is this not possible?

Comment: Do you have the possibility of changing the structure of the yaml? The result that you are expecting is possible, but not with the current structure of yaml.

Comment: @Dreamystify `js-yaml` the way to go, and you should edit the master and workers key to array e.g. `loadedConfig.all.workers = Object.values(loadedConfig.all.workers)`. The problem with an array of workers is that you'll lose the yaml structure because arrays have only numeric keys, and "worker_1" would have to be a custom key of itself next to "ansible_host" and "image" properties. It's just a JSON after all, edit it for your needs as you consider.

Comment: @DhruvShah no its an Ansible hosts file and has to remain usable.

Comment: @darklightcode thank you, I think i will need to look at another hosts file format

Comment: @Dreamystify in that case, if your objective is to loop over the `worker` and `master` hosts, I think even with the current JSON you should be able to do it using `Object.keys(workers)`, as this will return you the `worker_ids` in an array.  It would be a bit easier to assist you if you could specify what exactly needs to be done once you loop over or count the hosts.

Comment: Please note that as is your ansible inventory is not valid. If you don't intend to actually use this as an inventory in ansible, you might consider changing the structure to something that best suit your needs. If you do intend to use it with ansible, you need to make the grammar valid (i.e. adding intermediate `children:` and `hosts:` elements....) which will break all the current implementation clues you've already got. Note that with a valid inventory `ansible-inventory -i /your/inventory --list` will return a json containing `hosts:` lists for each groups that might be easier to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML-to-JSON parsing is correct.
If you intend to read the values of the `worker` and `master` hosts, you can still do it in the following way:

```js
const hosts = {
  all: {
    masters: { 
      master_1: {
        ansible_host: "m1",
        image: "m1_image"
      }
    },
    workers: { 
      worker_1: {
        ansible_host: "w1",
        image: "w1_image"
      }, 
      worker_2: {
        ansible_host: "w2",
        image: "w2_image"
      } 
    }
  }
};

const { masters, workers } = hosts.all;
const masterHosts = Object.keys(masters);
const workerHosts = Object.keys(workers);

// printing their lengths
console.log('masters', masterHosts.length);
console.log('workers', workerHosts.length);

// printing worker hosts
masterHosts.forEach(masterId => {
 console.log(masters[masterId].ansible_host);
  console.log(masters[masterId].image);
})

// printing worker hosts
workerHosts.forEach(worker => {
  console.log(workers[worker].ansible_host);
  console.log(workers[worker].image);
  // uupdating the hosts.
  workers[worker].ansible_host += '_updated';
});

console.log(hosts)
```